# calculating mean of a random variable raised to a power

Tags: variance, mean

Given the mean & variance of a dataset of linear measurements X ... N~(14,2), I want to find the mean of X^3.

So by taking mean as being expected value, & rearranging: -

$$Var(X)=E[X^2]−(E[X])^2$$

I get

$$ E[X^2] = Var(X) + (E[X])^2$$

$$E[X^2] = SD^2 + (E[X])^2$$

How can I go from this to using an exponent of 3 to solve the original problem?

Answer (score 5):

Easy way is to use [moment generating functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function). For the normal this is

$$M(t) = e^{t\mu + \sigma^2t^2/2}$$

Then we can get the moments by using

$$\text{E}[X^n] = \left.\dfrac{d^n M(t)}{dt^n}\right|_{t=0}$$

the $n$th moment is the $n$th derivative of the moment generating function evaluated at 0. For your particular example we get

$$\begin{align*}M(t) &= e^{t(14) + (2)t^2/2}\\
\dfrac{d^3 M(t)}{dt^3} &= (8t^3 + 168t^2 + 1188t +2828)e^{t^2+14t}\\
\left.\dfrac{d^3 M(t)}{dt^3}\right|_{t=0} &= 2828
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Many thanks bdeonovic - Is this approach still possible if the exponent in not an integer, e.g. 2.4?

Comment: No... What would the 2.4th derivative be?????

Comment: Non negative integers only

Comment: Yes - that's what I was thinking.  In addition to the original question involving X^3, I need to calculate for X^2.4.  Is there any approach that may be used for this?

Comment: Just use definition of expectation. $E(g(X)) = \int_{-infty}^{infty} g(x)f(x)dx$ where $f(x)$ is the normal pdf

Comment: See fractional derivatives in https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/317095/expectation-of-square-root-of-sum-of-independent-squared-uniform-random-variable/317475#317475